# Network Simulation on SimPy

Tags: python, simpy

I am trying to simulate a network link that is used by many nodes to communicate on [SimPy](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (a python library). I have taken the network as `simpy.Resource(env, 1)` because all communication channels are FIFO in general. Whenever a node needs to send data, it requests the network resource and then transfers data.

```
def transfer(env,data_size):
    net_delay = data_size/WAN_BANDWIDTH
    with network_queue.request() as req:
        yield req
        yield env.timeout(net_delay)
```

But because of this, nodes transferring huge data are occupying the channel and small transfers are getting queued. I know for sure that this is not how real network transfers work. Every transfer gets an equal and divided amount of bandwidth. Any suggestions to solve this?

The following is what I came up with.

```
def transfer(env,transfer_size):
    transfer_size_remaining = transfer_size
    while(transfer_size_remaining>0):
        with network_queue.request() as request:
            yield request
            
            data_size = min(transfer_size_remaining,MTU)
            yield env.timeout(data_size/WAN_BANDWIDTH)
            
            transfer_size_remaining -= data_size
```

I am will be requesting the network queue and `MTU` (1500 Bytes) amount of bytes with every request. I think this should automatically make it round-robin and diving equal amount of bandwidth between all the nodes that are transferring data.

Is anything wrong with my solution? Are there any better ways to do it? Or is there a standard right way to do this with SimPy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution looks good.  I think that is what my first try would look like.  I am not seeing the issue Ye is trying to raise

The one thing you might want to consider is using a priority resource where a node's first transfer gets a higher priority then its later transfers.  The benefit is small one transfer jobs will not get hit with big queue times if your queue is filled with a bunch of huge multi transfer jobs.  The downside is if your workload is made up of mostly small jobs, then the big jobs will never get any resource time since the small jobs will have higher priority.  But that problem can be fixed by adding a interrupt to re-submit the big jobs with a higher priority if the big job sits in the queue too long.  Of course the best workload strategy (and there is a lot of them) depends on the make up of the work load.

Answer (score -1):

You should create another process to realise the timeout. Otherwise, it will be blocked by the first yield.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).